# How to remove specific HTTP response headers in PHP?

Tags: php, header, http-headers

I'd like to remove the following headers:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Win32)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=66
```

Comment: Do you even know what these header fields are used for?

Comment: uhmm ..yeah, i think they speak for themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this can be done properly in PHP, as these headers are set by Apache.

There is PHP 5.3's [`header_remove()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php) but that can remove only headers set by PHP (If I understand correctly). You could also overwrite the undesired headers by sending them again with empty values, but the original values will be sent anyway.

The best thing would be to fix this at the root, in Apache's configuration. For example, the [`ServerTokens`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servertokens) directive can change the "Server:" header.

Related: [`apache_response_headers()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php)

Comment: What do you mean by "set by PHP"? Do you consider `Host`, `Connection`, `Content-Type`, and `X-Powered-By` "set by PHP"?

Comment: @Pacerier `header_remove()` can only remove headers set previously by `header()` within PHP. The first two headers you mention are generally set by Apache. Whether `x-powered-by` can be removed using `header_remove()` I don't know, but I would guess no. `Content-type` can be set by the PHP script and when it is, it can probably be revoked by `header_remove()`.

Comment: I seem to be able to remove `x-powered-by` here. Isn't this set by Apache? Where is the line between Apache and PHP?

Comment: @Pacerier it's probably set by PHP

Answer (score 2):

You could turn your script into a non-parsed-header CGI. For that you have to rename your `example.php` script into `nph-script.cgi`, make it executable (+x) and add the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi
<?php
```

This requires you to send **ALL** http headers yourself however, including the `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` status line. (see rfc2616 php.ini config)

Oh, and actually I have no clue if this still works for current Apache versions.

Comment: What's the equivalent of `#!/usr/bin/php-cgi` on Windows?

Comment: @Pacerier There isn't a true equivalent. You'll have strip the shebang, bind the `.php` file extension to the cgi interpreter, or manuall invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP (or any other server site language) and sending the header Connection: close. This will cause Apache to omit the Keep-Alive header, since the connection is no longer keepalive. e.g.

```
header('Connection: close');
```

Not sure if it works same on all types of servers, suggestions welcome.

Read More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367741/apache-get-rid-of-keep-alive-entry-in-the-headers-list)